# Ajax Button to load more Posts into a timeline

Tags: loop, ajax, buttons

I am setting up a timeline page for a customer and so far i have designed the timeline and i am using 2 loops to place the posts in 2 columns (left and right) where the first post is located at the top of the left column and the second post is loacated at the top of the right column. Short: The left loop loads odd posts and the right one the even posts.

Now i have to implement a button at the bottom of the timeline to load 3 more post in every loop. I never used AJAX with a wordpress loop so I have no Idea how to solve this.
The coding will not be the problem but the idea how to make it! Hope some of you guys have an idea or even made something like this in the past :)

I add a code snippet of the loop:

```
<div class="timeline_container">
    <?php   $args = array(
'post_type' => 'Timeline',
'paged' => $paged,
'meta_key' => 'wpcf-datum',
'orderby' => 'meta_value',
'order' => 'DESC',
'posts_per_page' => '6',
);?>
      <?php query_posts( $args ); ?>
      <div class="timeline_left">
<?php if (have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : $i++; if(($i % 2) == 0) : 

$wp_query->next_post(); else : the_post(); ?>
   <div class="timeline-box">

      *here goes the post*


<?php endif; endwhile; else: ?>
<div>Alternate content</div>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

The second loop, for the right column looks exactly the same except that it asks for `($i % 2) != 0)`.

Comment: Do **NOT** use `query_posts`, it is **bad**. See [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/1753/22534) and [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/50761/22534) thread for more information.

Comment: See [Codex: AJAX in Plugins](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) to get you started.

Comment: Thanks so far. Now I have changed the loop but still no idea how ti implement AJAX. Hope I will get it done with any tutorial.